# How to pass the result of a form to another website with cURL?

Tags: php, html, curl

I am a student who is new to the web developing world.Please bare w/ me for having some mistakes and insufficient knowledge.

Currently studying about the PHP cUrl, because according to my friends and base on my research, it is the php library that would fit in my current project still not sure though.

I am creating a form, were a user inputs something then clicks the submit button, the result in the form then will be pass to another website and then i will output that result.

Never had a background in using cUrl and just recently learned its basic structure.
So I'm posting this to get some suggestions on how I can use it for my project. Appreciate all the help tnx.

Basic Structure that I currently learned below:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://somesite.com');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer))
{
    print "Yeah.<p>";
}
else
{
    print $buffer;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of these **`cURL`** parameters

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POST,1); //You have to enable the POST 
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$yourformfields); //Your form fields will be sent here
```

### Rewriting your example...

```
$username=$_POST['username'];//values from your form
$password=$_POST['password'];
$yourformfields="username=$username&password=$password";
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://somesite.com');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$yourformfields);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer))
{
    print "Yeah.<p>";
}
else
{
    print $buffer;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just try an HTML-only solution by directly setting the form action to the url on the other website. No need for cURL or PHP in that case. You might also want to try method="get" if method="post" does not work.

```
<form action="http://otherwebsite.com/formhandle.php" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```